# Can Play Cache be used outside of Play?

Tags: java, caching, playframework, akka

I am trying to understand https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaCache but cannot see how to incorporate it into an Akka project. In particular, the examples are incomplete. For example

```
import play.cache.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Application extends Controller {

    private AsyncCacheApi cache;

    @Inject
    public Application(AsyncCacheApi cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    // ...
}
```

How do I instantiate Application, such as in a unit test case? Where do I actually get an AsynchCacheApi instance to pass into new Application(cache)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use play caching, use https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/common/caching.html instead.